# Get the image id using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am getting the image content and stored it in the variable.

How do i get the id of the image using jquery.

```
var imageContent = "<img src='http://xxxx.com' width='30' height='40' id='img_123' />";
```

Comment: How did you get imageContent? Show that code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a jQuery object and get its id

```
$(imageContent).attr('id')
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/9gmhU/)

Answer (score 4):

You create a jquery object and get the id of it..

```
var id = $(imageContent)[0].id
```

Comment: Near-identical answers, *one second* apart. :-) We even used the same variable name.

Answer (score 1):

```
var imageContent = "<img src='http://xxxx.com' width='30' height='40' id='img_123' />";
var id = $(imageContent).attr("id");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(function(){
  var imageContent = $("<img src='http://xxxx.com' width='30' height='40' id='img_123'/>");
 console.log(imageContent.attr("id"));
})
```