# How to select an particular image using javascript or css

Tags: javascript, css-selectors

How to select an particular image in table or `<div>` using javascript to get an `id` of image selected.

I want to save an image which is selected to an database according to username 
I think the above javascript is used to select the image but it is not working :

```js
function imgWindow() {
   var s = window.getSelection()
   var r = document.createRange();
   r.selectNode(document.images[a, b, c]);
   s.addRange(r);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="images/p1.jpg" id="a" align="center" width="100" height="100" onclick="imgWindow()" />
  <img src="images/p2.jpg" id="b" align="center" width="100" height="100" onclick="imgWindow()" />
  <img src="images/p3.jpg" id="c" align="center" width="100" height="100" onclick="imgWindow()" />
  <img src="images/p2.jpg" alt="b" align="center" width="100" height="100" onclick="imgWindow() ">
</div>
```

`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the image id using jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20759020/get-the-image-id-using-jquery)

Comment: @MatthiasSteinbauer How is this a possible duplicate of that question?  This question doesn't even have the jQuery tag.

Comment: In general the question is overly simplistic. It could easily have been answered by any of the aprox. 50 questions that the duplicate utility brought up. I don't believe that this particular question contributes much value to the community.

Comment: @MatthiasSteinbauer you really should have marked it as a duplicate of a more relevant question then. The question you flagged it against is jquery only.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback will do that in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass parameter image itself to imgWindow function then you can get id of image by prop()

```js
function imgWindow(img) {
  //none juery version
  console.log(img.id)
  
  //jquery version
  console.log(($(img).prop("id")))
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <img src="images/p1.jpg" id="a" align="center" width="100" height="100" onclick="imgWindow(this)" />
  <img src="images/p2.jpg" id="b" align="center" width="100" height="100" onclick="imgWindow(this)" />
  <img src="images/p3.jpg" id="c" align="center" width="100" height="100" onclick="imgWindow(this)" />
  <img src="images/p2.jpg" alt="b" align="center" width="100" height="100" onclick="imgWindow(this) ">
</div>
```

Comment: He didnt say he was using jQuery